# Why image elements in SVG export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg

I have this illustration in .ai format that I try to export to SVG.

When it is exported the resulting file is so big.

Opening the SVG file I notice that it consists of lots om image tags/elements. And it is these that are causing the file to be so big.

Why are those image elements created and is there some way to export it without creating image elements and instead use paths etc.

Comment: How is anyone here to know?? We have no clue with the original artwork looks like or what the SVG code looks like. Raster images **are** created if you use things like glows, drop shadows, blurs, transparency and blending modes in Illustrator.

Comment: @scott Thanks a lot, that was what I was asking for (What causes raster images to be created in an svg export). Is there ways to decrease quality of only these raster images when exported?

Comment: Yeah go to *Effect > Document Raster Effect Settings...*. OTOH you should newer be in a position where you dont know your file has raster elements. Its kind of failure to do vector graphics.

Comment: You could use some of the SVG effects available in Illustrator for drop shadows and blurs, etc. When the SVG is exported, these won't be converted into raster images in the SVG file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raster images are **auto-generated** in Illustrator if the artwork contains effects such as glows, drop shadows, and blurs.

Raster images *may be* auto-generated in Illustrator if the artwork contains transparency and blending modes. It depends upon how the artwork with transparency/blending interacts with other objects.

If you wish to have zero raster..

Do not use **any** of the "effects" which create glows, drop shadows, or cause a "blur" (such as Gaussian Blur and Feather effects).

In the case of transparency/blending, it *may be* possible to merely flatten the artwork (`Object > Flatten Transparency` with the art selected) and retain the overall appearance.